# DNS Records (Nettica.com)

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

If someone uses Nettica.com (to manage DNS records), is there any chance, how to find out hosting provider?

**Example**

http://who.is/dns/evernote.com/

```
evernote.com NS 1 day  dns5.nettica.com
evernote.com NS 1 day  dns1.nettica.com
evernote.com NS 1 day  dns2.nettica.com
evernote.com NS 1 day  dns3.nettica.com
evernote.com NS 1 day  dns4.nettica.com
```

**Questions**

- Which hosting provider does Evernote use?
- Why Evernote use Nettica.com? What's the advantage?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS and webserver hosting can be totally independent. As is in this case.

Your best bet is:

- **Check the DNS records**:

  ```
  host evernote.com
  ```

  should give you something like this:

  ```
  evernote.com has address 205.234.25.136
  evernote.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
  [...]
  ```

  We know that web hosting is done at 205.234.25.136, and e-mail gets handled by Google (Apps for Your Domain).
- **Try checking the obtained IP in RIPE database**: [Query RIPE Database](http://www.db.ripe.net/whois?form_type=simple&full_query_string=&searchtext=205.234.25.136&do_search=Search)

  Here it's a nondescript IANA-BLK, so we don't know much.
- **In that case we can try a traceroute to the web host:**

  ```
  traceroute evernote.com
  [...]
  18  border3.pc1-bbnet1.sje.pnap.net (66.151.144.9)
  19  qts-28.border3.sje.pnap.net (70.42.255.234)
  20  205.234.0.42 (205.234.0.42)
  21  www.evernote.com (205.234.25.136)
  ```

  Looking at this we can make a guess that evernote is using www.internap.com

  Correction: As pointed out - ARIN database is more accurate in this case:

  http://ws.arin.net/whois/?queryinput=205.234.25.136

Comment: Now when I look at pQd answer - it's probably more precise. Internap could be an intermediary provider of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

check to what ip does evernote.com point:

```
pqd:~$ dig +short evernote.com
205.234.25.136
```

[ or just http://www.robtex.com/dns/evernote.com.html ]

and 205.234.25.136 belongs to [Quality Technology Services Santa Clara](http://www.qualitytech.com/).

[ http://www.robtex.com/ip/205.234.25.136.html#whois ]